# how can I stop certain javascript files from loading on internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

our website works fine on the latest ie10,firefox and chrome, however with ie9 below, certain js files have issues. I am aware of conditional scripts for IE but I would like to tell IE 9 and below not to load specific js files. How can I do so?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9 ]>
  <script src="/js/my_ie_script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Have u tried the line you put in your question?? is there an issue with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Less Than IE 9 where you want Less Than Equal IE9:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9 ]>
     <script src="/js/my_ie_script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Note that your problematic JS will still load in IE, you should surround them with

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
     <script src="/this/is/ok/to/load.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```